# Does anyone know the name of this tool?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

Can any one name this tool? 
Found it online and haven't found anything yet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it was part of a culinary, taxidermy, or leather carving set it may not have a trade name, only a name uniquely given by the manufacturer of that set.

Comment: Where did you find it online ? Perhaps there are some clues there to find.

Comment: craigslist of all things. 
https://atlanta.craigslist.org/nat/wan/d/woodstock-what-is-this-tool/7079305731.html

I used to work in a tool store for a number of years and it's been on my mind as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> Does anyone know the name of this tool?

That tool is called a ***scorp.*** Specifically, that scorp looks like it is designed for block print carving, the act of cutting an image out of a block of wood or a thick piece of leather to be used in printmaking. Scorps are different from gouges or other carving tools in that they're meant to be drawn (pulled) towards yourself, instead of pushed away.

Other, larger scorps are made by bending larger flat blank into an oval or rounded shape:

[image: spoon scorp]

These are meant for carving out the hollows in a spoon or other "dishing" actions.

Some scorps resemble really tiny draw knives, and are used like draw knives, but with a single handle (versus one on each end of a draw knife):

[image: draw knife scorp]

Confusingly, some larger scorps do actually have two handles, which essentially makes them a curved version of a typically-flat drawknife:

[image: two handed scorp]

Sometimes they are designed to be used by one hand or the other, and are open on one side, not forming a complete loop. For example, this is a "right handed" scorp:

[image: right handed scorp]

Comment: Thank you! You don't know how much this helped.

Comment: I do not believe this is the correct  name for the tool in question.  The bottom side of the tool is flat, drawing it across wood would not cut into the wood unless you were to draw it along the edge as if to make a chamfer.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I agree that the bottom side is flat, but not all scorps are curved. Some are flat (such as the drawknife scorp in my answer) and meant to be used as you're describing, or the blade forms an angle (like the right handed scorp in the images I posted) and they're meant to cut a groove or a sharp corner. Flat and angled scorps are common in block print carving since you're usually trying to make a well-defined shape instead of a gentle curve.

Comment: @dwizum. The draw knife example you posted is not the same as the tool in question and appears to have definite cutting blade that appears  as if it has a curve to it.. A  scorp by definition has **one** primary function; **To Hollow** ( according to Woodcarving Illustrated Magazine ) not for chamfering. Searching for "flat scorp" yields no results and searching for scorp leads to the explanation of  the one primary function i mentioned. I am not questioning all the info you posted in you answer about scorps, i am simply stating, i do not believe that the tool in the OP's question is a scorp.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely to be a wood or leather carving tool, seen many similar, but can be used for other materials.

Comment: I'm not sure that I consider this to be an actual answer.  In fact it doesn't appear to have any sort of cutting edge which makes its usefulness in carving wood or leather questionable.

Comment: @jwh20 I have seen and used these - while the cutting edge may not be clear in the image the ones I have used cut with a pulling motion and are useful for making "tracks" or "crevices" to make sure things like stitching can rest below the surface.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a windshield locking strip tool. I have one with 2 sides and used it to install the rear window on my 1956 Chevy wraparound rear window. It installs the gasket into the groove and locks the glass I to the opening. Similar to this 
https://www.classicindustries.com/product/153818.html[image][image]